# How to add a 3rd party MIB file to Windows SNMP?

Tags: windows, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I'm currently using SnmpMgrOidToStr Function from the SNMP Management API to capture SMNP traps (via the Windows default SNMP Trap Service), and translate them into strings.

However, SnmpMgrOidToStr only translates the default MIB installed on Windows. I now have a requirement to add a 3rd party MIB file to Windows MIB.  How can I do this?  I've tried copying the MIB file to System32 but it doesn't work.  There's also no .index file to delete, unlike NET SNMP.

I've tried searching the web but to no avail. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to write your own Windows SNMP Extension, which is a .dll you write and compile.

You load the .dll into your Windows Registry and restart your Windows SNMP service. You'll most likely have to write your own MIB database, which is the coded implementation of your 3rd party MIB. It will be a long process.

Hopefully this will get you started: [MS SNMP Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)